# What does Elim $\land$ actually eliminate

Tags: logic

Say I were to have the premise

$$P \land \sim Q \implies R$$

And I were to apply the Elim $\land$ inference rule, would the result of that lead to just P, or can the elim be simply applied to the $P \land \sim Q$, creating $P \implies R$?

Comment: It's hard to be sure, because I don't know for certain what rule you mean by “Elim $\land$”, but the answer is probably “Neither of the things you said is correct.”

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rule called $\land$-elimination is:

> $P \land Q \vdash P$ [and: $P \land Q \vdash Q$].

It licenses the derivation of one of the two *conjuncts* of a *conjunction*.

If we read the formula:

> $P ∧ \lnot Q \to R$

as: $P ∧ (\lnot Q \to R)$, with $\land$-elim we can derive $P$ and $\lnot Q \to R$.

Thus, the rule is used to "unpack" a conjunction and derive its conjuncts separately: it "eliminates" the occurrence of the connective: $\land$.

*Note*. If we read the formula as: $(P ∧ \lnot Q) \to R$, this is not a *conjunction*; thus, $\land$-elim does not apply.